# How to color properties/classes/ whatever you call them. Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax, colors, highlight

https://gyazo.com/b8e7470ec2c1edb3c72fc9b2402b2170

I want to color the Transform and LineRenderer one color.
I want to color Vector's one Color.

Like legit there's not a single universal name for these i don't get it.

I've colored them before. But I had to reinstall Visual Studio and forgot to back up my syntax hightlighting. I literally can't find the option.
It's a 100% not under User Types or User Members. I've turned all of those to Bold or a different color. And it still won't color the '-insert name here-

Tried the 2017 version.

```
private Vector3 Test0;
private Transform Tes1t;
private LineRenderer Test2;
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/03c6550b2bf3addd16b19481f70264b4

These are all set to either bold or a color.
yet my transforms or line renderers are not bold or colored.

Comment: Did you create the `Transform` and `LineRenderer` types yourself? If not, it's not a "_User_ Type".

Comment: @Sweeper well what is it then?

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio on me right now, but there should be another item in the list called "XXX Types".

Comment: I've been looking through it multiple times. There's nothing i've been trying to import some color schemes too and they don't seem to color them either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that visual studio intellicode  wasn't isntalled properly or corrupted somehow reinstalling fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

It's in Tools/Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors

Find *User Types* where you can assign different colors for classes (`Transform`, `LineRenderer`) and structs (`Vector3`).

[image]